# Expressing iterative version of fold in terms of recursive version

Tags: functional-programming

**1st Definition. Recursive definition of fold**

fold$_{recur}$ (c,h) nil = c

fold$_{recur}$ (c,h) (cons(a, x)) = h(a, fold$_{recur}$ (c,h) x)

**2nd definition of fold. Iterative definition**

fold$_{itr}$ (c, h) nil = c

fold$_{itr}$ (c, h) (cons (a, x) ) = fold$_{itr}$ (h (c, a), h) x

How do I express fold$_{itr}$ in terms of fold$_{recur}$.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you have tried to solve your problem on your own, then explaining what approaches you have tried and why you are stuck will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 3):

For easier typing let me rename $\mathsf{fold}_{recur}$ to $\mathsf{foldr}$ and $\mathsf{fold_{itr}}$ to $\mathsf{foldl}$ (an additional reason for the renaming will soon be apparent).

Then we have
$$\mathsf{foldr} \,(h,c) \,[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n] =
  h(x_1, h(x_2, \ldots, h(x_{n-1}, c) \ldots ))$$
and
$$\mathsf{foldl} \,(h,c) \,[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n] =
  h(\ldots h(h(c, x_1), x_2), \ldots, x_n).
$$
That is, your two different folds are also known as the *right* and *left* fold in functional programming languages. You are asking how to get the left fold in terms of the right fold. The short answer is "by reversing the list".

Suppose we had a list reversing function $\mathsf{rev}$. Then we could define
$$\mathsf{foldl} \, (h,c) \, \ell =
  \mathsf{foldr} \, ((\lambda (x,y) . h(y,x)),c) \, (\mathsf{rev} \, \ell).
$$
We just need $\mathsf{rev}$ expressed in terms of right fold:
$$\mathsf{rev} \, \ell =
  \mathsf{foldr} \, (\mathsf{append}, \mathsf{nil}) \, \ell
$$
and
$$\mathsf{append}(x, \ell) =
  \mathsf{foldr} \, (\mathsf{cons}, \mathsf{cons}(x,\mathsf{nil})) \, \ell.
$$
You can fold all these definitions into one fat definition of $\mathsf{rev}$, if you want to impress your teacher.

Comment: What is $\lambda$

Comment: I will also open a different question of equality of foldl and fold$_{itr}$. I am looking for an algebraic proof between the two functions. I will open a question and paste the link here. Also thanks a bunch for answering. Also this question is not for an assignment . I am self teaching myself and got stuck on this.

Comment: I have opened a question here. 

http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/46847/proving-equality-between-foldl-recursive-and-iterative-fold

Comment: You can still impress your teacher even if you're teaching yourself. And $\lambda$ is function abstraction, as in $\lambda$-calculus and functional programming. How can it be that you are studying `fold` without knowing what $\lambda$-calculus is?

Comment: Hmmm...I have heard of λ calculus but I havent read on it yet, I dont really see it as an obstacle for now, most functional programming I find is inductive reasoning. But I will read up on λ calculus soon.

Comment: If you are learning about folding of lists you should read about $\lambda$-calculus *right away*. By the way, $\lambda$-calculus *is* an algebraic theory in the sense that it is an equational theory. But it is *higher-order* because the equations involve functions, rather than just algebraic operations and elements.

Comment: In any case, you can remove $\lambda$ from my answer by defining $g(x,y) = h(y,x)$ and then using $g$ instead of $\lambda (x,y) . h(y,x)$. Would that make you happy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28815/discussion-between-abdul-rahman-and-andrej-bauer).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to link a similar question on stackoverflow asked in scala to this question

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136794/foldleft-using-foldright-in-scala][1]