# Proving equality between foldl recursive and iterative fold

Tags: functional-programming, correctness-proof, induction

Hi I have two definitions of fold. I will call them foldl which is recursive and fold$_{itr}$ which is iterative.

I am looking for an **algebraic proof** that the two definitions are equal ideally through **structural induction**.

**Definition for foldl**

```
foldl(c,h) nil = c

foldl(c, h) (list, element) = h (foldl (c, h) list, element)
```

**Definition for fold$_{itr}$**

fold$_{itr}$ (c, h) nil = nil

fold$_{itr}$ (c, h) (element, list) = fold$_{itr}$ (h(c, element), h) list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two definitions are **not equal**. Consider $h$ defined by
\begin{align*}
h(c, a) = 10 \cdot c + a
\end{align*}
and $c = 0$. Then
$$\mathsf{foldl} \, (c,h) \, [1,2,3] = 321$$
but
$$\mathsf{fold}_{itr} \, (c,h) \, [1,2,3] = 123.$$